# break free from while loop when enter key entered in c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define BAR 1
#define BELL 2
#define LEMON 3
#define CHERRY 4
#define RMAX 4

void main()
{
    int slot1, slot2, slot3;
    char anykey;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Type any key to start the slot machine \n");
        scanf(" %c", &anykey);
        if (anykey == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }
        srand(time(NULL));
        slot1 = 1 + (int)rand() % RMAX;
        slot2 = 1 + (int)rand() % RMAX;
        slot3 = 1 + (int)rand() % RMAX;

        if (slot1 == slot2 && slot2 == slot3 && slot1 == 1)
            printf("Congradulations On A JACKPOT\n");
        else if (slot1 == 1 || slot2 == 1 || slot3 == 1)
            printf("ONE dime \n");
        else if (slot2 == slot1 && slot2 == slot3)
            printf("One Nickel \n");
        else printf("Sotrry better luck next time\n");
    }
}
```

I made a code like this and I want to break free from while loop when
enter key is pressed
so I add the code if `(anykey=='\n')` but it doesn't work
what is wrong with my code

Comment: The whitespace in your ` %c` is consuming the newline. Having the newline as a break condition is a really bad idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf(" %c", &anykey);` consumes the newline from `stdin` before actually reading any character, which is why `anykey` never actually ends up being `\n`

If you must have the newline as a break condition (as in hitting enter will stop the program), you're better off using `getchar` for this, you can use `scanf("%c", ...)` but that's a bit overkill.

```c
printf("Type any key to start the slot machine \n");
int ch = getchar();
/* Should check for `EOF` too */
if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF)
{
    break;
}
anykey = (char) ch;
```